# Is there any UTXO based coin contract?

Tags: contract-design

I'd like to create an UTXO style coin contract to trace each coin movement. There are many account based coin contracts, but I couldn't find any UTXO coin contract. Are they any samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token contracts are based on functionality that is baked-in to ethereum, including the ability to send from one address to another, which provides your traceability.

Building another mechanism in a smart contract just to provide UTXO functionality is therefore a bit of an unnecessary exercise, and possibly very expensive. If traceability is what you need it is already available.

Comment: Could you explain your way to trace the coin contract transactions? Do I need to parse Ethereum transactions? or did you mean event logs?

Comment: Yes you need to parse the blockchain to trace anything. But there are blockchain explorer like https://etherscan.io/ if you have a small number of things to trace